# How to automatically assign libraries in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

In the Server List of my SAS Enterprise Guide session I have a white (unassigned) library which I can right-click to assign. Is there a programming statement, perhaps a libname statement, or task, that I can use in an EG project to automate this step?

Comment: These libraries have been defined in the metadata, probably through the SAS Administrator software (forgot exact name). If i recall, there you can configure if a library should be loaded immediately or not. So if you have admin rights, you can change it for certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `SAS Management Console`.

Go to `Data Library Manager`,  find the library you want to modify, right-click for `Properties`.

Go to `Options` tab - click `Advaced Options` button - check `Library is Pre-Assigned` checkbox.

You should have METAAUTORESOURCES option enabled on your application server.

Comment: Any method of doing it within EG, without access to SAS MC?

Comment: No, it's server-side setup, not client-side.

Answer (score 5):

On the presumption that your libraries are white but already assigned - ie that you have to right-click 'assign' to gain access (and they turn yellow). You can automatically assign in code using a 'meta' libname statment. Something along the lines of this should work:

```
libname MYLIB meta LIBRARY=MYLIB;
```

Of course you could change the 1st MYLIB to any lib reference you want but it makes sense to keep them the same as the pre-assign by IT.

Answer (score 3):

Open `SAS Enterprise Guide`

`Tools` --> `Options`

Go to `SAS Programs` in left pane

Check box next to `Submit SAS code when server is connected`

Go to `Edit` next to `Submit SAS code when server is connected`

Add libname statement `libname lib 'directory';`

`Save`

Hope this helps.